# Select entries with today and tomorrows date

Tags: mariadb, query, datetime, date

I am using MariaBD and am trying to filter entries with todays date and tomorrows date.

I have managed to filter todays date using

```
SELECT *, 
       DateTime AS Time 
FROM table
where status = 'Pending' 
and DateTime like concat(CURDATE(),'%') 
order by DateTime
```

I am struggling to add in entries with tomorrows date as well. Probably very easy but noting I am trying is working

I am using MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following where clause:

```
  SELECT ... WHERE DATE(MyDateField) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1);
```

Comment: `WHERE MyDateField >= CURRENT_DATE AND MyDateField < ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 2)` would be much more efficient.

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation mentions no difference.

Comment: The function/conversion `DATE(MyDateField)` would prevent the use of any index on MyDateField.